# About generating a list of a values (e.g. [1,1,1,2,2,2]) according to a context free grammar

Tags: sml, context-free-grammar

I want to generate a context free grammar style list of integers with SML.

The syntax is like `S -> 1 S 2 | epsilon`.

And this is what I tried

```
fun gen(n: int) = 
    if n = 0 then []
    else 1 :: gen(n - 1) :: 2
```

The expected result for `gen(3)`, for example, should be `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`.

However I got this error relating to the types.

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]
  operator domain: 'Z * 'Z list
  operand:         'Z * int
  in expression:
    gen (n - 1) :: 2
```

So how should I implement it? Thanks in advance and any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, using pattern matching:

```
fun gen 0 = []
  | gen n = 1 :: gen (n-1) @ [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it, I should do

```
fun gen(n: int) = 
    if n = 0 then []
    else 1 :: gen(n - 1) @ [2]
```